# How can I use map operator to add a new field to an object into an array returned into an Observable?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am pretty new in RxJS and working on an Angular probject I have the following problem.

Into my component I am retrieving an **Observable<Patient[]>** using this service method (it is retrieving it from Firebase FireStore DB):

```
  getAllPatients(): Observable<Patient[]> { 
   
    return <Observable<Patient[]>> <unknown>this.firestore.collection('patients').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(snaps => 
        snaps
          .map(snap => snap.payload.doc)
          .map(doc => ({
            UID: doc.id,
            id: doc.id,
            firstName: doc.get("firstName"),
            surname: doc.get("surname"),
            completeName: `${doc.get("firstName")} ${doc.get("surname")}`,
            birthDate: doc.get("birthDate"),
            placeOfBirth: doc.get("placeOfBirth"),
            socialSecurityCode: doc.get("socialSecurityCode"),
            personalEmail: doc.get("personalEmail"),
            personalPhone: doc.get("personalPhone"),
            occupation: doc.get("occupation"),
            contactReason: doc.get("contactReason")
          }))
      )
    );

  }
```

Where **Patient** is the following interface:

```
export interface Patient {
    firstName: string;
    surname: string;   
    completeName: string;
    birthDate: any; 
    placeOfBirth: string;
    socialSecurityCode: string;
    personalEmail: string;
    personalPhone: string;
    occupation: string;
    contactReason: string;
    birthDateStr?: string;
}
```

As you can see it contains these 2 fields:

1. **birthDate: any;**: it is retrieved from FireStore and it is a date field.
2. **birthDateStr?**: it is not retrieved from FireStore and I have to build it starting from the previous **birthDate** field as a string.

So in my component code originally I had something like this to retrieve my data (it worked fine):

```
// Load the list of all the patients from the DB:
async loadPatientsList() {
    this.patientsList$ = await this.patientService.getAllPatients()
    console.log("patientsList$: ", this.patientsList$);
    //this.loading = false;
}
```

Now I have the problem that for every **Patient** object into my **Patient[]** array of my Observable I have to add this **birthDateStr?** extra field setting the **birthDate** field value of the current object as a string.

I think that I have to use RxJS and I am trying to do in this way:

```
// Load the list of all the patients from the DB:
async loadPatientsList() {
    this.patientsList$ = await this.patientService.getAllPatients()
        .pipe(
          map(fields => {
            let temp = { ...fields, 
                         birthDateStr: fields.birthDate..... // HERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO !!!
                       }
            return temp;
          })
        );
    console.log("patientsList$: ", this.patientsList$);
    //this.loading = false;
}
```

So basically I am trying to use the RxJS **map** operator in order to add this field. Basically I am creating a brand new **temp** object containing all the **fields** of the original object.

Then I am trying to create the new **birthDateStr** starting from the **birthDate** that should be containined into the original fields, by this line:

```
birthDateStr: fields.birthDate..... // HERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO !!!
```

The problem is that now the IDE give me the following error on the previous line (on the **birthDate** property):

> Property 'birthDate' does not exist on type 'Patient[]'.ts(2339)

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue? Moreover how can I finalize my code in order to convert this date field into a string representing my date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `fields` is actually an array of patients: `Patient[]`

Therefore, you will need to map over that array to add the new `birthDateStr` field to each patient:

```
// Load the list of all the patients from the DB:
async loadPatientsList() {
  this.patientsList$ = await this.patientService.getAllPatients()
    .pipe(
      map(patients => {
        return patients.map(fields => {
          return {
            ...fields, 
            birthDateStr: fields.birthDate // <-- do whatever conversion you need here
          };
        })
      });
}
```

---

Perhaps you could just add the `birthDateStr` field in your service though:

```
getAllPatients(): Observable<Patient[]> {   
  return <Observable<Patient[]>> <unknown>this.firestore.collection('patients').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(snaps => 
        snaps
          .map(snap => snap.payload.doc)
          .map(doc => ({
            UID: doc.id,
            id: doc.id,
            firstName: doc.get("firstName"),
            surname: doc.get("surname"),
            completeName: `${doc.get("firstName")} ${doc.get("surname")}`,
            birthDate: doc.get("birthDate"),
            placeOfBirth: doc.get("placeOfBirth"),
            socialSecurityCode: doc.get("socialSecurityCode"),
            personalEmail: doc.get("personalEmail"),
            personalPhone: doc.get("personalPhone"),
            occupation: doc.get("occupation"),
            contactReason: doc.get("contactReason"),
            birthDateStr: "..." // <-- HERE
          }))
      )
    );
}
```